# Accessing "User Info" dictionary in CoreData from IOS Application

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7

I've created some ManagedObjects and for each of them I added the *User Info*  Key/Value of **DisplayName**

Example:

```
       Attribute: eReader
   User Info Key: DisplayName
 User Info Value: E-Reader

      Attribute: weather 
  User Info Key: DisplayName
User Info Value: Weather Radar
```

I was hoping to Query the entire *NSManagedObject* from code and then iterate through each attribute and display their **DisplayName** on the screen.  Any guidance as to how to do this?

This way I could show a table of User Readable text but each entry was mapped to the correct NSManagedObject attribute which cannot start with either uppercase or have spaces in them.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answers here [UserInfo Dictionaries on CoreData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230614/userinfo-dictionaries-on-coredata)

```
for (NSString *key in [ei.attributesAsDictionary allKeys]) {
    NSAttributeDescription *attributeDescription = eiEd.attributesByName[key];
    NSString *displayName = attributeDescription.userInfo[@"DisplayName"];
}
```